# Multiple View Controllers with Nav Bars

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have the below set up. I want two view controllers to be embedded in one navigation controller so that I can move between them with the "back" bar button. This works fine but I can't use the storyboard to add a title to the second view controller or add any bar buttons to the second view controller. It feels like the navigation bar isn't showing up for the second view controller. I tried to drag a nav bar into the second view controller but it doesn't show up when I run the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer involves the segue. By changing the segue to the depreciated Push and then back to Show, it added the navigation bar back and I am now able to add bar items.